# sqlalchemy showing an error related to os.getenv()

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am working on **sqlalchemy** and there's command in it engine -
 `create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))`.

When I run the program it shows an error saying -

> "Could not parse rfc1738 URL  from string 'C:\Program Files\ PostgreSQL\10\data"

**Code**

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

#engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
  flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destinaiton, duration FROM      flights").fetchall()
  for flights in flights:
    print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "list.py", line 7, in
>   
>       engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))   File "C:\Users\Amber
>   Bhanarkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py",
>   line 424, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Amber Bhanarkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py",
>   line 50, in create
>       u = url.make_url(name_or_url)   File "C:\Users\Amber Bhanarkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py",
>   line 211, in make_url
>       return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)   File "C:\Users\Amber Bhanarkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py",
>   line 270, in _parse_rfc1738_args
>       "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name) sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string
>   'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data'

Please someone help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The engine URL shouldn't be a path to your local Postgres installation but a sting that tells SQLAlchemy how to connect to the database. It has the following format:

```
postgresql://username:password@server:port/databasename
```

Comment: Using the above statement I get an error saying - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'

Answer (score 2):

I'm also watching course video of cs50 now. You should try to just use `create_engine("your_database_url")`.

If you still want to use `create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))` tp process, make sure you can log in using the command line like this `psql $DATABASE_URL`.

Answer (score 1):

using `psql $DATABASE_URL` works for me but I'm still getting the same error on `create_engine("your_database_url")`

```
(project1) C:\Users\Gregory Goufan\Downloads\CS50s Web Programming with Python and JavaScript\project1\project1\project1>psql postgresql://openpg:openpgpwd@localhost:5432/postgres
psql (9.5.8)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

But it is true that by putting the url direct in create_engine funciton works strange thing because it is indeed a string which is returned

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string ' 'postgresql://openpg:openpgpwd@localhost:5432/postgres''
```